# Regex pattern to match string like "Viewing 1 to 10 of 100"

Tags: javascript, regex

can anyone please help me with regex pattern which matches string like 
"Viewing 1 to x of n"
where x and n are any number

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? If you want debugging help, you can post it here

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free regex service, show us your attempt

Comment: provide some example and your efforts

Comment: Use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-use-a-variable-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This pattern will match your  `Viewing (.*\d) to (.*\d) of (.*\d)`
If you are stuck on having the first number as `1` just replace the first `.*\d` with `1`.

And you can retrieve values in `matched groups` (basically of values of the three numbers in the string),  using details mentioned in this question.

[How do you access the matched groups in a JavaScript regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression)

Edit:
Add groups as per suggestion from @Probie

Comment: I think he wants to use a variable in `x` and `n`

Comment: @MasOOd.KamYab Maybe, but the way i read the title says that hes probably looking to find string that have pagination info. Viewing 1 to 2 of 5 or so on.

Comment: Might be worth adding parens around the `.*\d`s so that he can actually retrive his `x` and `n` (which is what I read the question as asking)